# whether to combine or to split table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I can't figure out what is the better solution.

A table : 35 of fields and 2 of them are longtext type. (Already built-in in the CMS that I'm about to use)

B table : similar amounts of fields and 3 of them are text type.(Newly required data for my project)

At first, I decided to use already existing 'A' table and add new 'B' table. It's far easy way 'cause the CMS already provides the classes and methods (etc - search, crud...) that is needed to my project.

But, my concern is the performance. Since table 'B' is sort of add-on to 'A', most of the DB actions, like showing list, searching, getting contents..., must refer at least those two tables at once each time.

JOIN and multiple queries are absolutely needed. And this site needs to show many lists and contents to online users at same time.

What would be the best solution? Is combining two tables more efficient, or re-using the already-existing codes as much as I can and preserving compatibility to the CMS?

ps. If I combine two tables, I can reduce some of the unnecessary varchar fields in table 'A'.

Comment: if both are properly indexed, there shouldn't be a performance problem. Selecting the only needed columns also helps.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner isn't joining tables affects performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only duplicate columns that you will use to relate tableB with tableA.  Reasons why you shouldn't duplicate non-primary key columns:

a. table size grows and it's a waste of space if there are duplicate fields between tables. 
b. regardless of the column size to be duplicated, it's very laborious maintaining tables just to make sure all duplicate columns are updated correctly.  Think for example there's a duplicate column named detail.  If you update this column in tableA for a particular id, then you need to make another effort to update the corresponding record in tableB.    
c. Will consume lots of effort, resources, time, and money to maintain duplicate non primary key columns between tables.

Answer (score 0):

Combining 2 tables is too expensive and not wise.  If those two tables contains duplicate fields, you will waste lots of database space which will impact the CRUD operations.  Best approach is to create table B but add only the primary key[s] fields from table A that you can use to link the two tables. In this way it will be easy to retrieve to both tables for data you specifically need.  You also don't need to retrieve all data from both tables.

Example:

**Table A:** 
id 
fname 
lname 
. 
. 
rest of the 35 fields

**Table B:** 

tableb_id 
id (from table A) 
. 
. 
rest of table B fields

**Your Query:** 
Select column[s] 
From TableA, TableB 
Where TableA.id = TableB.id 
And (all other conditions like TableA.lname = "Santos"); 
 
**or use Inner Join** 
 
SELECT column_name(s)  
FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.ID 
WHERE (all other conditions like TableA.lname = "Santos");

Comment: Currently I'm duplicating 4 columns including primary key (id, member_id...) for reasons. Is this too much?